# Convert string with parameters into object

Tags: c#, string, object

Is possible to convert a **String** with the following text 
`"{ id = 123 }"` into an **Object** 
`{ id = 123 }`?

Comment: do you mean `object str = "{ id = 123 }";`? its possible to have any type as object. if you mean object with parameter `id` set to 123 then its not directly possible. you have to define a class and parser to convert string into that object

Comment: Do you absolutely have to follow this syntax `{ id = 123 }` or you want something like it?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, I tried your example, but, I received the same value that I got. For example, I get `"{ id = 123 }"`, and when I try `object str = "{ id = 123 }"`,  the result is the same `str == "{ id = 123 }"`

Comment: @PhilippeParé, I do have to follow this syntax

Comment: I would convert the strings to Json, replacing `=` by `:`. This way, you can use a library such as Json.Net and deserialize the objects from there.

Comment: Are you trying to make a custom class?  Your question is a little ambiguous.  Something like `public class MyCustomObject{ string id {get;set;}}`  then you can get and set your id with something like this.  `MyCustomObject myObject = new MyCustomObject(); myObject.Id = "123";`

Comment: `Object` can't have any additional properties. It is very unclear what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use JSON as string input (if possible of course) and deserialize it using something like [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).
The string then will have to look like this: 
{
    "id": 123
}

Comment: While good suggestion OP later made clear that "I do have to follow this syntax"...